# how to validate a form using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, validation

Say I have a form with a few textFields and a submit button.

What would be the best way, once the user clicks this button, for javascript to validate the textFields ( at least, make sure there's something in there ) and, if not, pop out a message, if everything OK, the submit the form and php will take over.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+validation

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation

Comment: I would recommend to use onchange event to validate each textfield separately. Use a check flag next to each input also .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add an `OnClick="function_name();"` in the html of your submit button,

and in the declaration of the function do this

```
function function_name(){
     var str = document.getElement("your_text_field_id");
     if (str=="") {
       alert("Please type some text first");
       return false
     } else { 
       alert("Thanks");  //optional
       return true;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Call a JavaScript function which validates user input fields using the forms onSubmit method.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery (if not, you should) you can do something when the form gets submitted through `.submit()`. Within this event you can check all the `input` fields depending on their type, if an error occurs you can call `event.preventDefault()` to stop the submitting and `alert()` an error.

Something like this:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#myform').submit(function(event){

    error = false;

    $('input',this).each(function(){

        if($(this).val() == '')
            error = true;

    });

    if(error == true){

        event.preventDefault();
        alert('An error occured!');

    }

});
```