# My form adding blank field on refreshing the page

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to validate a form using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454875/how-to-validate-a-form-using-javascript)

I want to use javascript thats my form will not add any data to table on refresh or by blank field my code is here

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="">
    Name <input type="text" name="name" /> <br />
    Website <input type="text" name="website" /> <br />
    Description <input type="text" name="description" /> <br />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
    <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query("insert into ".PRO_TABLE_PREFIX."tutorial ( name, website, description )
    values('{$_POST['name']}','{$_POST['website']}','{$_POST['description']}')");

    ?>
```

Comment: [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) is going to have a field day with that SQL call.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/emozom/3/edit)

```
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();" action="aaa">
        Name <input type="text" class="txt" name="name" /> <br />
        Website <input type="text" class="txt" name="website" /> <br />
        Description <input type="text" class="txt" name="description" /> <br />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validateForm(){
            var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('txt');
            var errors = '';
            for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                if(!arr[i].value){
                    errors += arr[i].getAttribute('name') + ' cannot be blank\n';
                }
            }
            if(errors.length){
                alert(errors);
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: You have the validate executing on submit click and form submit, it should only be on the form submit. I would suggest concatenating errors into a single alert though instead of multiple alerts. It's better for UX - the user can correct all errors at once.

Comment: @MrCode how its possible? I m new to php

Comment: Yet code adding data automatically when i refresh the webpage how to get rid of?

Comment: Showing no error but when i click on submit button its add the blank filed in table

Comment: +1 for the update. @Developer_7 The code in this answer is syntactically and logically correct, therefore you must be doing something wrong. Check your error console.

Comment: @AkhilSekharan will you help me plzzzzzz

Comment: See the console and let me know what's the error

Comment: Undefined index: name
Undefined index: website
Undefined index: description

Comment: Add console.log(arr) to my code after var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('txt'); and let me know the output

Comment: @AkhilSekharan same error
Notice: Undefined index: name in D:\\wp-content\plugins\pro-questions\admin-list-site.php on line 104

Notice: Undefined index: website in D:\\wp-content\plugins\pro-questions\admin-list-site.php on line 104

Notice: Undefined index: description in D:\\wp-content\plugins\pro-questions\admin-list-site.php on line 104

Comment: and line 104 it this
`values('{$_POST['name']}','{$_POST['website']}','{$_POST['description']}')");`

Comment: Did you check the html from your browser if its rendered as you want?

Comment: for the console.log(arr) . can you see the list of input html in your developer tools

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier //wp-admin/admin.php?page=list-site (1):218
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost///wp-content/plugins/pro-questions/images/menu.gif

Comment: when i click on submit button its add the blank filed in table

Comment: I have added a demo. check it out

Comment: @Akhil Sekharan the output is 403 Forbidden

Forbidden

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: name 
Notice: Undefined index: website 
Notice: Undefined index: description

Comment: @AkhilSekharan help me plz

Comment: @waqas, i was out for lunch. updated my demo